# Order of a Function

Tags: functions

If $f(x)$ is a function, then we define the function $f^{(n)}(x)$ to be the result of $n$ applications of $f$ to $x$, where $n$ is a positive integer. For example, $f^{(3)}(x)=f(f(f(x)))$.

We define the $\textit{order}$ of an input $x$ with respect to $f$ to be the smallest positive integer $m$ such that $f^{(m)}(x)=x$.

Now suppose $f(x)$ is the function defined as the remainder when $x^2$ is divided by $11$. What is the order of $5$ with respect to this function $f$?

I wrote out the pattern as 5, 10, 9, 7, 3, 6, 1, 2, 4, 8, 5
I got 11, but it was wrong. What should the answer be?

Comment: Your pattern goes wrong right away - $f(5)$ should be the remainder when $25$ is divided by $11$, which is not $10$.

Comment: How did you get your sequence?   $5^2=25\equiv 3\pmod {11}$, so $f(5)=3$.

Comment: Ah yeah you are right. My new pattern is 5 3 9 4 5. Should the answer be 4 or 5 in this case?

Comment: $f^{(4)}(5) = f^{(3)}(3) = f^{(2)}(9) = f(4) = 5$, so the order is $4$.

Comment: thank you everyone :)